# How can I prevent an emacs error message window from stealing focus and requiring extra steps to dismiss?

Tags: emacs, clojure, window, focus, clojurescript

I use plain emacs in a terminal and like it that way (no spacemacs or gui emacs for me). In the gui versions, error messages pop up in a floating window, I think, and can be batted away. In my setup they open in a new split window and steal focus. To get rid of it I have to move the pointer back to my code window and then, if I want my code window full width, maximize the code window by deleting the other error window with a binding (which keeps the error window in the buffer list for reference). It's a lot of keystrokes for a simple error message. Ideally, I would like to not lose the focus from my code when they appear, and banish the error message window with a single binding (but keep it in the buffer list for reference... ideally being able to recall it in the way it initially appeared [in a split, without stealing focus] with another binding?

It is possible to dismiss an error window with C-x 0 (delete-window) if it has focus, but if previously you had two windows open in, say, a horizontal split, the error appears in the other window, and dismissing the error window removes your previous split. I create lots of unpredictable configurations so using a window arranger will not work for me to restore some preconfigured window arrangement.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly if the errors you mention are compilation errors when developing Clojure/script but, in my experience (I also use Emacs in a terminal), you can dismiss the error message just by pressing `q` and it will close the frame and move the cursor back to the original frame.

Here's a short video of my experience: https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Jzq.jpg

I also tried it having more than one frame, and it works as expected: it splits only the code editor frame to show the error; if you dismiss the error it removes the new frame and will keep your existing layout.

Comment: That would be perfect! Pressing q doesn't do anything on my machine, but I'll try to figure out why.

Comment: Well, after some digging around, I found out the q was being overriden by another mode. I rebound it to another shortcut and I'm so, so happy this is working now.

Answer (score 3):

you can disable this behavior by setting two cider config vars to `nil`:

`cider-show-error-buffer` and `cider-auto-select-error-buffer`,

this would prevent the default behavior, still allowing you to manually select error buffer when needed with `cider-selector`.

Still i find it more convenient to use the [popwin](https://github.com/m2ym/popwin-el) package for that, showing the error buffer as a popup, without breaking your windows layout.

`(push "*cider-error*" popwin:special-display-config)`

Comment: I'll give popwin a crack! Looks like it might be really useful for this, or even other things.

Comment: Well, at first install, it doesn't become a destination for cider errors, but maybe some tinkering will make that work.

Comment: I installed popwin and it is a very cool addition... thank you for telling me about this!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to enable `winner-mode` and just bind `winner-undo`/`winner-redo` to keys you want to cycle between window configurations.  After an error pops up a new frame, it is just one call to `winner-undo` to restore the prior configuration.  This also gives you the desired behaviour for recalling the error configuration with `winner-redo`.